# HTTP HEAD request with HttpClient in .NET 4.5 and C#

Tags: c#, .net, httprequest, .net-4.5

Is it possible to create a HTTP HEAD request with the new `HttpClient` in .NET 4.5? The only methods I can find are `GetAsync`, `DeleteAsync`, `PutAsync` and `PostAsync`. I know that the `HttpWebRequest`-class is able to do that, but I want to use the modern `HttpClient`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding Http Headers to HttpClient (ASP.NET Web API)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12022965/adding-http-headers-to-httpclient-asp-net-web-api)

Comment: This is not a duplicate. I want to read only the response headers of the request I've made, and this is possible using a HTTP HEAD request. It has absolutely nothing to do with the thread you have mentioned.

Answer (score 136, accepted):

Use the `SendAsync` method with an instance of `HttpRequestMessage` that was constructed using `HttpMethod.Head` .

`GetAsync`, `PostAsync`, etc are [convenient wrappers](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System.Net.Http/System.Net.Http/HttpClient.cs#L144) around `SendAsync`; the less common HTTP methods such as `HEAD`, `OPTIONS`, etc, don't get a wrapper.

In short:

`client.SendAsync(new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Head, url))`

Answer (score 19):

You may also do as follows to fetch just the headers:

```
this.GetAsync($"http://url.com", HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead).Result;
```

Comment: The beauty of this approach is that it works **even if the target server explicitly disallows `HEAD` requests** (e.g. Amazon AWS).

Comment: From a code standpoint, I like this option and Ian's remark is also an advantage.  But I implemented this one and Smigs' answer and Smigs' answer performed considerably faster...granted, my Urls point to 30-100MB files which may have something to do with that.  But this answer makes a GET request rather than a HEAD so keep that in mind.

Comment: I'm getting a "method not allowed"

Comment: If there is connection change/ redirection, this solution actually follows the connection. Just retrieving the header of the original url will get you a 200 response even when doing a full get may actually fail.

Comment: As @jasonxz observed, this does make a full GET request.  It allows you to access the headers as soon as they're available, but still does pull the rest of the data down.  So if you're trying to conserve bandwidth when you just want the headers but to not download a possibly large body, this isn't the solution.

Answer (score 6):

I needed to do this, to get `TotalCount` of ATMs that I was returning from my Web API's <kbd>GET</kbd> Method.

When I tried @Smig's answer I got the following Response from my Web API.

> MethodNotAllowed : Pragma: no-cache X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?dfdsf Cache-Control: no-cache Date: Wed, 22 Mar 2017 20:42:57 GMT Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0 X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319 X-Powered-By: ASP.NET

Had to built upon @Smig's answer to get this working successfully. I found out that the Web API methods needs to explicitly allow the **`Http HEAD`** verb by specifying it in the **Action** method as an Attribute.

Here's the complete code with inline explanation by way of code comments. I've removed the sensitive code.

#### In my Web Client:

```
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        // set the base host address for the Api (comes from Web.Config)
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("ApiBase"));
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add( 
          new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        // Construct the HEAD only needed request. Note that I am requesting
        //  only the 1st page and 1st record from my API's endpoint.
        HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(
          HttpMethod.Head, 
          "api/atms?page=1&pagesize=1");

        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);

        // FindAndParsePagingInfo is a simple helper I wrote that parses the 
        // json in the Header and populates a PagingInfo poco that contains 
        // paging info like CurrentPage, TotalPages, and TotalCount, which 
        // is the total number of records in the ATMs table.
        // The source code is pasted separately in this answer.
        var pagingInfoForAtms = HeaderParser.FindAndParsePagingInfo(response.Headers);

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            // This for testing only. pagingInfoForAtms.TotalCount correctly
            //  contained the record count
            return Content($"# of ATMs {pagingInfoForAtms.TotalCount}");

            // if request failed, execution will come through to this line 
            // and display the response status code and message. This is how
            //  I found out that I had to specify the HttpHead attribute.
            return Content($"{response.StatusCode} : {response.Headers.ToString()}");
        }
```

#### In the Web API.

```
    // Specify the HttpHead attribute to avoid getting the MethodNotAllowed error.
    [HttpGet, HttpHead]
    [Route("Atms", Name = "AtmsList")]
    public IHttpActionResult Get(string sort="id", int page = 1, int pageSize = 5)
    {
        try
        {
            // get data from repository
            var atms =  _atmRepository.GetAll().AsQueryable().ApplySort(sort);
            // ... do some code to construct pagingInfo etc.
            // .......
            // set paging info in header.
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers.Add(
              "X-Pagination", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(paginationHeader));
            // ...
            return Ok(pagedAtms));
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            //... log and return 500 error
        }
    }
```

#### FindAndParsePagingInfo Helper method for parsing the paging header data.

```
public static class HeaderParser
{
public static PagingInfo FindAndParsePagingInfo(HttpResponseHeaders responseHeaders)
{
    // find the "X-Pagination" info in header
    if (responseHeaders.Contains("X-Pagination"))
    {
        var xPag = responseHeaders.First(ph => ph.Key == "X-Pagination").Value;

        // parse the value - this is a JSON-string.
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PagingInfo>(xPag.First());
    }

    return null;
}

public static string GetSingleHeaderValue(HttpResponseHeaders responseHeaders, 
    string keyName)
{
    if (responseHeaders.Contains(keyName))
        return responseHeaders.First(ph => ph.Key == keyName).Value.First();

    return null;
}
```

}

Comment: @Kiquenet Hi, I updated the answer with the `HeaderParser.FindAndParsePagingInfo` source.

Comment: What is `paginationHeader` variable in method `IHttpActionResult Get` ?

Answer (score 3):

Solved it by doing

```
 var result = await client.SendAsync(new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Head, url));
```