# How to decompress GZipped HTTP response in WinRT

Tags: c#, http, windows-runtime, httpwebrequest, gzip

In usual .NET environment we have a property AutomaticDecompression in class HttpWebRequest.

```
httpRequest.AutomaticDecompression = 
    (DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate);
```

Problem is that i am on WinRT, and here is no such property in HttpWebRequest class. And what i have? I have GZip-compressed response stream...

Answer (score 1):

Use the HttpClientHandler, as it supports the AutomaticDecompression:

```
System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler hc = new System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler();
hc.AutomaticDecompression = System.Net.DecompressionMethods.GZip;

System.Net.Http.HttpClient client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient(hc);

var result = await client.GetAsync(uri)
```

Comment: You can do that with the Client and the ClientHandler: [Timeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient.timeout%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) [Headers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12022965/adding-http-headers-to-httpclient-asp-net-web-api) [Allow AutoRedirect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclienthandler.allowautoredirect%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)

Comment: There is no System.Net.Http at all in portable library framework. Unsolved

Comment: This code works perfectly fine for me in a WindowsRuntimeComponent library.

Comment: @Croll docs say HttpClient is available in portable .Net platforms https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.110).aspx