# curl commands to C# mbed API

Tags: c#, rest, mbed

can anyone help me translating this curl command to C# https GET request?

```
curl -v -H 'Authorization: Bearer <your_access_key>' https://api.connector.mbed.com/endpoints/
```

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: [`WebClient`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.net.webclient) is your friend.

Comment: Or HttpClient with additional Headers.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35907642/custom-header-to-httpclient-request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer <your_access_key>");
string response = client.DownloadString("https://api.connector.mbed.com/endpoints/");
```

Comment: perfect thanks a lot for your answer, it worked with the URI within quotation marks

Comment: If an answer solved your problem please tick the answer as 'Accepted' (with the little checkbox). Thanks!

Comment: sorry for that I'm new here and this was literally my first question