# Intercept HTTP traffic and add a custom header

Tags: c#, winforms, httpwebrequest, httplistener

I have a C# windows forms application and one third party dll do some API calls to a server where I want to intercept the HTTP request going from my application and add a custom header by updating the request.
Is that possible to do in WinForms/C# without using a proxy service? If so how do I intercept the request being sent from my application?

Comment: Have you seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35910012/2309376)?

Comment: yes but it's not what I want as my server api call hasn't a way to add authentication header I want to fire an event when each api call occurs and before request sent to server I need to update the request with adding an authentication header

Comment: Are you saying you want to be able to do this without modifying the application itself ( which would make it rather simple)?

Comment: yes as the server api couldn't change I need a way to add authorization header with intercepting the HTTP traffic that going from my application.is that possible?