# StatusCode: 415, ReasonPhrase: 'Unsupported Media Type', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent

Tags: c#, .net, dotnet-httpclient

I would like to post a new resource to an endpoint using the .NET HttpClient. However, I am getting an error message. Doing the same operation with same headers and same content in Postman, the post operation succeeded without any errors. The error messages states that:

```
StatusCode: 415, ReasonPhrase: 'Unsupported Media Type', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
  X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
  X-UA-Compatible: IE=edge
  X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
  X-Generator: Drupal 8 (https://www.drupal.org)
  Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
  Connection: Keep-Alive
  Transfer-Encoding: chunked
  Cache-Control: must-revalidate, no-cache, private
  Date: Tue, 08 Oct 2019 16:24:17 GMT
  Server: Apache/2.4.39
  Server: (Win64)
  Server: OpenSSL/1.1.1c
  Server: PHP/7.2.19
  X-Powered-By: PHP/7.2.19
  Content-language: en
  Content-Type: application/vnd.api+json
  Expires: Sun, 19 Nov 1978 05:00:00 GMT
}
```

I also tried to use the PostAsync method direct on the HttpClient instance instead of using the HttpRequestMessage instance. However, this option is not working as I would like to set my custom headers in the request. The DefaultRequestHeaders.Add option seem not support this. I am using code as suggested on a similar question at [Custom header to Httpclient request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35907642/custom-header-to-httpclient-request). Below is my code.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;


namespace ConsoleApp6
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            //the string that needs to be posted to endpoint. 
            string dd = @"{'data': { 'type': 'node--settings','attributes': {'title': 'Mail Server3'}}}";

            //outputting my text here to make sure that the text is a valid json.
            Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(dd));

            //my http client using suggested solutions on the internet and here on stakeoverflow. 
            var client = new HttpClient();
            var httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage
            {
                Method = HttpMethod.Post,
                RequestUri = new Uri("http://localhost/pg/jsonapi/node/settings"),
                Headers = {
                { HttpRequestHeader.Authorization.ToString(), "Basic YXBpOmFwaQ==" },
                { HttpRequestHeader.ContentType.ToString(), "application/vnd.api+json" }
            },
                Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(dd).ToString())
            };

            //posting the data here to the endpoint and capturing the request.
            var response = client.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage).Result;

            //here is the response I am getting. 

            Console.WriteLine(response);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

I am expecting the operation to return `Status: 201 Created`. The status message I am getting is `StatusCode: 415, ReasonPhrase: 'Unsupported Media Type'`. Other answers to the same problem indicate this is a server error. In my case, I do not think so, since, I am achieving the correct result in Postman as indicated [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uOJJzesZU8ab5OagN6w-4Aax_RWnoMdD/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: `"application/vnd.api+json"`, try `"application/json"`

Comment: Hi @Matthew, I have tried this and it did not work. The content type I am sending is correct per endpoint specification.

Comment: The Content-Type header is a property of the content, therefore will probably be ignored on the `HttpRequestMessage.Headers` object.
Try setting the header on `HttpRequestMessage.Content.Headers` and see what you get. As a rule of thumb, if in doubt about a header, try the HttpRequestHeaders.Add(...) method. If its an unrecognized header (in the context) an Exception will be thrown, which will tell you that the header is placed on the wrong `HttpHeaders` instance. The concept in `System.Net.Http` is a bit weird - to me, a header is a header is a header...