# Passing Custom header in httpclient

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a .net core 3.1 azure function apps that calls Azure API. I am passing a custom header "Request-Id", my custom header is a Guid converted to string. I don't know but for some reason, when my request reaches to the API Server the "Request-Id" header value changed.
For example, I passed E2AD0ABE-9D8F-4D7E-BFAB-AA8A756DF9D2 in the "Request-Id" header but when it reached the API it become 3794FBB7-1564-4BD9-86B9-F136AF9D61DF|.898989834

I tried it in .net core2.0 client and it's working ok. I don't know if this is a bug in .net core 3.1 or I just need to do it(passing custom header) on a different way.

```
        var requestId  = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var uri = "https://testurl/v1/Pr/";
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage
            {
                Method = HttpMethod.Post,
                Content = sc,
                RequestUri = new Uri(uri)
            };
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Request-Id", requestId);
           
             var result = client.SendAsync(request).Result;
            if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                response = result.StatusCode.ToString();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Custom header to Httpclient request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35907642/custom-header-to-httpclient-request)

Comment: You mean `client` as request or `result` as response changed the header string?

Comment: What does fiddler say.

Comment: What do you mean with I tried it in Net core 2? Do you mean the client is NET Core 2 or the server or both? Because if it’s just the client, that would be very weird.

Comment: You mean "Request-Id" sent in HTTP request gets changed to some other GUID/random string when it reaches to server?

Comment: I mean .net core 2.0 client. Yes "Request-Id" is sent in Http request get changes to some other Guid/random when it reaches to server

Comment: @Jawad, Thanks for suggestion but it doesn't resolve the issue.

Comment: did you check the Azure API Mgmt Transformation policies? you can also try to rename your custom header entry.