# Method wrapper in c#

Tags: c#, .net, authentication

I have the following class:

```cs
class Loader 
{
    private string accessToken { get; set; }
    private string refreshToken { get; set; }

    private void Auth()
    {
        // ... retrieving access and refresh tokens or updating the access token
    }

    public Task<T> Get(string id) 
    {
        try
        {
            // ... send get request and return the result
        } 
        catch (HttpRequestException exception)
        {
            if (e.statusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
            {
                await this.Auth();
                return await this.Get(id);
            }

            throw exception;
        }
    }
}
```

I wrote only `Get` method, but there will be more, like `Put`, `Delete` and so on. In every method I have this repeating part: if the request returned 403 status code, try again. Writing it in every place is a lot of copypaste. Is there a better way to achieve this functionality?

In JS I would simply create a function wrapper, in Java I would use decorators for it. But no idea, how to achieve this in c# without copypaste.

Comment: You don't need an exception handler, `HttpClient.GetAsync`, `SendAsync` etc return a Response object with a status code. You can create a function wrapper in C# and in fact, it may be easier than JavaScript and a **lot** easier than java BUT that's a bad idea to begin with, even in JavaScript. API authentication is supposed to be done when you establish a connection to an API, through a client/service/whatever module, not something you do on every request. And certainly not something you do *after* the first request fails.

Comment: In fact, when you create an HttpClient instance you *know* it's not authenticated and can authenticate right away. If you use a typed Httpclient, you can do so in the factory method itself. [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71919860/how-to-add-bearer-token-authentication-to-typed-httpclient-in-asp-net-core-6) asks something similar: `How to add bearer token authentication to typed HttpClient in Asp.Net Core 6`. The rest of your code shouldn't have to care about authentication

Comment: Something like this? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/implement-http-call-retries-exponential-backoff-polly - Also see this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DSMdUvL8N30

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos It is not the whole code. I didn't paste it in the question because it does not really relate to the problem, as I thought. I do authentication on the Loader initialization. But the access token expires in some time and you'll now it expired by receiving 403. And the right way would be to retry auth and then try again. And I don't use HttpClient, I use a wrapper of it which does throw Exceptions (but I don't actually have access to this wrapper as it is written not by me and I have to use it)

Comment: It *is* relevant, because you *are* using HttpClient either directly or indirectly, and the correct time to authenticate is before the first call, not try every time. If you know you don't have a token, why try to make a call that fails? Typed HttpClients use HttpClientFactory and Polly too. All these things work through dependency injection. When your code requests a new HttpClient you *know* it's going to be called so you *know* you need to authenticate. You can avoid the failed call and the exception if you do so explicitly.  Polly is needed to eg refresh tokens that have expired.