# IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array from Http Client header

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

Getting following error while adding header to HTTP Client:

```
{"ClassName":"System.IndexOutOfRangeException","Message":"Index was outside the bounds of the array.","Data":null,"InnerException":null,"HelpURL":null,"StackTraceString":"   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add)\r\n   at System.Net.Http.Headers.HttpHeaders.AddHeaderToStore(String name, HeaderStoreItemInfo info)\r\n   at System.Net.Http.Headers.HttpHeaders.Add(String name, String value)
```

Following is the code how I am adding headers:

```
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("api_key", _apiKey);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("targetApp", "query");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("accept", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Application", _applicationName);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("TraceId", traceId.ToString());
```

This is an intermitter issue, to fix this we have to restart IIS, after this code work fine.

Thanks a lot for helping in advance

Comment: Is any other code accessing the default headers at the same time against this `client` instance? `traceId` in particular doesn't look much like a "default" header unless that client is tightly scoped. In other words: is this `client` instance reused by anything concurrent?

Comment: Yes, we are reusing on concurrent calls

Comment: We have a API client where we make rest calls, this code is written inside API Client.

in asp.net framework we were creating http client instance on each request but our team suggested that we should not create client request on each request

Comment: "we are reusing on concurrent calls"

well that's the problem, then; you should only configure the default headers once, while they're not is use; if multiple clients are manipulating them, then: chaos. The *default* headers should only be the shared values that don't change per request; per-request headers can be [set separately](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53451542/23354)

Comment: @MarcGravell Reusing HttpClient is good idea? Got it we should create http header every time and keep single instance of http client

Comment: reusing httpclient is strongly recommended; the problem is that you can't constantly be changing the default headers; use per-request headers for things that are per-request

Comment: @MarcGravell Thanks a lot, I implemented your suggestions, it is working well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created HTTP client as a single object and then set the default header at once and changed the logic to set changing header at request level:

[Custom header to HttpClient request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35907642/custom-header-to-httpclient-request/53451542#53451542)

I implemented suggestion made by @Marc Gravell, and it is working well, no issues in past 15 days.
Thanks a lot @Marc Gravell