# .NET Core Console Application JWT Authentication

Tags: cookies, soap, .net-core, jwt, console-application

I am creating a .netcore console application which makes API calls to a web application. Before it can make the API call, it needs to authenticate itself to the webapp. I am inheriting the **IClientMessageInspector** class and trying to add the JWT to **MessageHeader.CreateHeader** in the following manner -
`public object BeforeSendRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel)
 {
   request.Headers.Add(MessageHeader.CreateHeader("Cookies", "m3", "jwt="+GetTheJWT()));
 }`

I understand that the JWT is hardcoded and would expire after a time period but currently my concern is that the JWT that I am trying to add as a part of the Header is not getting reflected in the header. 
I am receiving the message as **HttpRequest** object in the web application and I see that JWT is missing as a part of the **Cookies** Property of the **HttpRequest** object.

The following are my queries - 
1) I wanted to know whether it could be done this way? 
2) What am I doing wrong? 
3) Is SOAP still relevant with .netcore or do I have to use REST API?
4) Is authentication still possible with SOAP on .netcore using JWT?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding Http Headers to HttpClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12022965/adding-http-headers-to-httpclient)

Comment: This has already been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12022965/adding-http-headers-to-httpclient