# Using multiple authorization schemes in blazor net core 6 - allow in if api key present, else redirect to login

Tags: c#, .net-core, blazor

I have a blazor app with azure ad auth, where human users are redirected to the microsoft log in screen etc, I now have a requirement that a tool needs to be able to access specific pages using a key in the header.

Is this possible? If so how do I add the second type of authorization where it effectively ignores the first type if the key is present?

Comment: http://codingsonata.com/secure-asp-net-core-web-api-using-api-key-authentication/

Comment: thanks @RobertHarvey how does that translate to a blazor app without controllers?

Comment: Sorry.  Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12022965/102937) as a starting point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### I use the following code :

#### Connection Database

get conncentionString from appsettings.json :

```
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("AppContext") ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Connection string 'AppContext' not found.");
```

Add DbContext :

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<AppContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseLazyLoadingProxies().UseSqlServer(connectionString, x => x.UseNetTopologySuite());
});
```

#### Add Identity

```
builder.Services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>(option => {
    option.Password.RequireDigit = true;
    option.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 5;
    option.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
    option.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
    option.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
    option.Password.RequiredLength = 16;
}).AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppContext>();
```

#### Add Authentication API JWT

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
    {
       ValidateIssuer = true,
       ValidateAudience = false,
       ValidateLifetime = false,
       ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
       ValidIssuer = "https://Example.com",
       IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("keyhash"))
    };
});
```

#### Add Authentication Web Cookie

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

}).AddCookie(options => {
    options.LoginPath = "/Login";
    options.LogoutPath = "/Logout";
    options.AccessDeniedPath = "/AccessDenied";
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(100000);
});
```

#### Used packages

```
 1. Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design Version="6.0.5"
 2. Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Proxies Version="6.0.5"
 3. Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.NetTopologySuite Version="6.0.5"
```